# gridfs-stream upload a file into mongodb not working in node.js server code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, gridfs, gridfs-stream

gridfs-stream upload a file not working, but download a file working plz give solution

```
app.post('/file', function(req, res) {
var busboy = new Busboy({
    headers: req.headers
});
var fileId = new mongo.ObjectID();
var file = filename();
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    if (!file) return res.send({
        result: 'NO_FILE_UPLOADED This Error by not upload any file'
    });
    console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
    var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        _id: fileId,
        filename: my_file.txt,
        mode: 'w',
        chunkSize: 1024,
        root: fs,
        content_type: mimetype
    });

// here how can i give a path to read stream ?
// File id is a mongodbid its ok. but what about file name

fs.createReadStream('/some/path').pipe(writestream);
}).on('finish', function() {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'content-type': 'text/html'
    });
    res.end('<a href="http://localhost:49106/file/' + fileId.toString() + '">download file</a>');
});
req.pipe(busboy);//its working
});
```

gridfs-stream file upload code is not working file download code is working very well.how can i set the path of the readstream files in the path.

Answer (score 0):

`busboy` never directly writes to disk. What you get is just a plain readable stream (`file`), so pipe that to your `writeStream`:

```
file.pipe(writeStream);
```

instead of:

```
fs.createReadStream('/some/path').pipe(writestream);
```

Also your `if (!file)` check will never execute, because `file` will *always* be defined, and `console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');` is wrong because there is no `data` variable in that scope.

Comment: even thou "file.pipe(writeStream); files not uploading into writestream..but if i add a file into mongodb using robomongo ..and give video id from that db.....its working....so only readStream working in this code.....write Stream not working....plz help me

Comment: Its Complete Code of my server.js please solve the writestream Problem

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate some more. "not working" doesn't tell me anything. Also, there is nothing wrong with the code in the gist you linked to.

Comment: I am also using the pips in the same way as you stated in your answer but the file upload size is always 0. I am really not sure what the problem is.